# MASM v6.11 - Strike a key when ready

Tags: x86, ide, dos, masm

I'm using MASM v6.11 from Microsoft Programmer's Workbench IDE from DOS. When I run my program I get the message `Strike a key when ready...` once the program terminates. It halts the screen which is fine but it's also interfering with what I am doing. Is there any way of disabling this text from coming up?

Comment: What environment are you running it from? Some kind of IDE? `Strike a key when ready` is a result of the PAUSE command being run after your program executes. Anyway, one could always put a wait for keyboard hit routine just before exiting that would keep the screen in a state you could view.

Comment: Never mind found it. Options - Editor Settings - set askrtn to no.

Comment: Using MASM PWB IDE and yes I normally do a wait in order to view the screen but that's still a bit of a pain. I can't see an option to just halt the screen without a message maybe there isn't one or I haven't found it as yet. It's not too bad as it does hold for about a second, not like TASM where its just a flash even on a 486. Thanks for your response Micheal.

Comment: Ah so you are assembling linking and debugging from DOS.

Comment: Yes and on a 486, writing a driver for some hardware I designed.